# How become works in ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

In Ansible I found some keywords like **become** and **become_user**. 
I am implementing ansible by making *server01* as ansible control node (from where I will write playbooks and will execute playbooks on other remote server/s) and *server02* as remote node.

*server01* - Ansible control node
Users of *server01* - root, vagrant

*server02* - Ansible remote node
Users of *server02* - root, test

Note: I am able to ssh *server02* using it's test user.

Suppose I have written a playbook for "tree" installation on *server02*.

```
---
  - name: Installation of software on ubuntu server
    hosts: PROD
    become: true
    tasks:
      - name: Install tree software
        apt:
          name: tree
          state: present
          update_cache: yes
```

Now, I have executed the playbook and I want to know the significance of become keyword.

From which user *server01* ansible-playbook will login into the *server02*. and why I used **become** keyword. Please also write about **become_user** keyword?

Comment: Is [this document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) insufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Your server01, running the playbook, will log into server02 using the `remote_user`. That's either the user running the playbook, or another user configured in your inventory, your configuration, or via the `ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER` environment variable.

`become` points at what happens next: When activated, the ansible process on server02 will ***become*** another user. Practically, it calls `sudo` for every command. Per default, the `become_user` is `root`.

Comment: i have not defined/configured any user in my inventory or in any other place. In this situation, what will be the user name thru which ansible server01 will login to server02? Can you please explain it using an example, it will be really helpful for me.